# fetch gmail calendar events in mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, google-calendar-api

I am working on mvc 4 web application. I want to implement a functionality wherein the scenario is as follows-
There will be gmail id as input for ex: abc@gmail.com. When user will enter this, application should fetch all the calendar events of that respective email id and display them.

I have gone through this-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx#cal_rest

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol

I am new to this and i have searched a lot but not got any solution. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error or problem are you having? Can you share what you have done and the problem that you are facing?

Comment: The problem i am facing is that i am not understanding how to begin over this

Comment: "this" means MVC or Google Calendar API? Are you familiar with ASP.NET MVC, HttpClient or HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Not familiar with google calendar api. I am familiar with rest that you have asked

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution . Just refer this.

https://github.com/nanovazquez/google-calendar-sample

Answer (score 0):

Please check the steps below.

1. Add Google Data API SDK.
2. Try this code.. I wrote this code for one project but I removed some codes that are not related to Google Calender. If you don't want to use SDK, you can simply do http-get or http-post to your calender link based on spec.

   ```
           CalendarService service = new CalendarService("A.Name");
           const string GOOGLE_CALENDAR_FEED = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/";
           const string GOOGLE_CALENDAR_DEFAULT_ALL_CALENDAR_FULL = "default/allcalendars/full";
           const string GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ALL_PRIVATE_FULL = "private/full";

           private void SetUserCredentials() {
               var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleUserName"];
               var passWord = Security.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GooglePasswrod"]).ToInsecureString();
               if (userName != null && userName.Length > 0) {
                   service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);
               }
           }        

           private CalendarFeed GetCalendarsFeed() {
               CalendarQuery calendarQuery = new CalendarQuery();
               calendarQuery.Uri = new Uri(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_FEED + GOOGLE_CALENDAR_DEFAULT_ALL_CALENDAR_FULL);

               CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed)service.Query(calendarQuery);
               return resultFeed;
           }

       private TherapistTimeSlots GetTimeSlots(CalendarEntry entry2) {


       string feedstring = entry2.Id.AbsoluteUri.Substring(63);
       var postUristring = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", GOOGLE_CALENDAR_FEED, feedstring, GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ALL_PRIVATE_FULL);

       EventFeed eventFeed = GetEventFeed(postUristring);
       slot.Events = new List<Event>();

       if (eventFeed != null) {
           var orderEventList = (from entity in eventFeed.Entries
                                 from timeslot in ((EventEntry)entity).Times
                                 orderby timeslot.StartTime
                                 select entity).ToList();

       }
       return slot;
   }

   private EventFeed GetEventFeed(string postUristring) {

       var eventQuery = new EventQuery();
       eventQuery.Uri = new Uri(postUristring);
       var h = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
       eventQuery.StartTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, h, 0, 0);
       eventQuery.EndTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, h + 2, 0, 0);
       try {
           EventFeed eventFeed = service.Query(eventQuery) as EventFeed;
           return eventFeed;
       }
       catch (Exception ex) {
           /*
            * http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-dataapi/browse_thread/thread/1c1309d9e6bd9be7
            * 
            *  Unfortunately, the calendar API will always issue a redirect to give you a 
               gsessionid that will optimize your subsequent requests on our servers. 
               Using the GData client library should be transparent for you as it is taking 
               care of handling those redirect; but there might some times where this error 
               occurs as you may have noticed. 
               The best way to work around this is to catche the Exception and re-send the 
               request as there is nothing else you can do on your part. 
            */
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```